# How to reference to a controller in another project with AngularJS $http url?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, http-get

This is how I do it if the C# controller is in the same project:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/SomeController/SomeMethod',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

I'm building a SPA, so I want my AngularJS stuff and the WebApi stuff to be in their own projects.

How it's done if the controller is in another project inside the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your url has to match your url of the Web API. Your problem will be that the port of your localhost will change everytime you start your webserver.
What you can do is setting this port.

For this you just go to the properties of your Web API project, choose the tab "Web" and then mark "Use Visual Studio Deployment Server" and enter a port.

If you take something like "1337" you can make your calls in Angular like that:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'localhost:1337/api/SomeController/SomeMethod',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

if would really suggest you to store a base url somewhere in your javascript code, so when you deploy your page some time soon, you'll just need to change one variable.

I hope this helps you

Comment: I tried the http://localhost:1357/api/SomeController/SomeMethod before and got this error:
_XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1357/api/SomeController/SomeMethod. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1357' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500._ I have no "Use Visual Studio Deployment Server" option, but I had to click on 'Create Virtual Directory' when changing my localhost port to 1357. Anyway, it doesn't matter, I get the same error as above.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2015.

Comment: Are you using any type of authentication?

Comment: No. Not yet, but I'm planning to.

Comment: Can you maybe screenshot your properties?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inform a full url, like:

```
http://localhost:5376/api/SomeController/SomeMethod
```

and in production, change to the IP or domain.

I like to create two constants files in my project:

URL

```
angular.module('app')
    .constant('URL', {
        local : 'http://localhost:54341/api',
        dev : 'http://...',     
        hom : 'http://...', 
        prod : 'http://...'
    });
```

Config:

```
angular.module('app')
    .constant('CONFIG', {
        env: 'local'
    });
```

And use like this:

```
var url = URL[CONFIG.env] + '/anotherPath';
```

You will likely have problems with POST, PUT (...) request. If so, search for **CORS** and **pre-flight** problems.